# curl CA issue in linux

Tags: curl, ca

I am trying to install "flow" with using "brew", but there are some errors about curl CA problem. I've already tried to do some of the solutions in the stackoverflow, but I couldn't figure out. Is there any idea?

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/facebook/flow/archive/v0.21.0.tar.gz
```

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the --cacert option.
>
> If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in 
>   the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a 
>   problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might 
>   not match the domain name in the URL).
>
> If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use 
>   the -k (or --insecure) option.
>
> Error: Failed to download resource "flow"

Comment: You can resolve this issue from here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/646594/how-to-fix-ca-cert-issues-with-curl-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I tried that solution but didnt worked